# Is it possible to save more than one public keys to keychain in ios, swift

Tags: ios, swift, rsa, keychain

I'm trying to generate `RSA` keys and save it to the keychain. I generate two public keys and one private key.

```
public key one -> generated using SecKeyGeneratePair & 
private key one -> generated using SecKeyGeneratePair

public key two -> generated using SecKeyCreateWithData
```

for all three keys `kSecAttrIsPermanent` property set to `true`.

then I'm retrieving keys with below method

```
func GetKeysfromKeyChain(tag: String) -> SecKey? {



        let query : [String: Any] = [
            String(kSecClass) : kSecClassKey,
            String(kSecAttrKeyType): kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
            String(kSecAttrApplicationTag): tag,
            String(kSecReturnRef): true
        ]


        var result: AnyObject?
        let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &result)


        if status == errSecSuccess {
            print("key existed :")
            return result as! SecKey?
        }

        return nil
    }
```

with above method, can successfully get `public key one` and `privat key one`. but for `public key two` it always returns a nil value. no idea .hope your help with this.

**this is how I generate public key two**

```
let data2 = Data.init(base64Encoded: serverPublicKey)


        let keyDict:[NSObject:NSObject] = [
            kSecAttrIsPermanent: true as NSObject,
            kSecAttrApplicationTag: "com.marlonbrand.serverpublic".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSObject,
            kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
            kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: 2048 as NSObject,
            kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPublic
        ]


        let publickeysi = SecKeyCreateWithData(data2! as CFData, keyDict as CFDictionary, nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the type of your `keyDict` to `[String : Any]` and doing the appropriate casts where you need them? If I had to guess, the casts to NSObject are probably messing it up.